# display:none is being appended to images uploaded to Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, display

I am uploading images as usual through the media uploader. They are uploading correctly, and I can see them in the media gallery and at the file URL.

However when I add an image to content, `style="display:none!important"` is added to its attributes.

The code, verbatim, for my image in the Wordpress text editor: `<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5393" src="https://mysite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Ads.png" alt="" width="565" height="294" />`

And the code, verbatim, for the image at the front end: `<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-5393" src="https://mysite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Ads.png" alt="" width="565" height="294" style="display: none !important;" hidden="">`

Where is this stray code coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer as I can't comment, but there's a good chance it's actually a stray piece of JavaScript adding the style. Compare the html output (view source) with an inspection of the DOM element. If the style is not there in the source, but is there upon inspection, it's likely to be JavaScript. Try removing JavaScripts one by one and see if you can find the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. How would a stray piece of Javascript like this occur?

Comment: Could it be a deliberate addition by someone with site access? I ask mainly because it worked fine before.

Comment: It certainly could, but it could also be something simple such as a conflicting plugin etc. I'd be happy to take a quick look at the front end if you have a publicly accessible URL? Might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Look for plugins that do anything related to images on the front end, e.g. lazy loading etc

Comment: So it turns out Wordpress was just hiding images if their width was smaller than the minimum specified width for a registered thumbnail size, which I've not seen before. I just specified a smaller size and the image worked. Haven't solved the underlying issue but it's a suitable workaround for now.